# Compression Ratio calculation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, image-compression

I am doing image compression but I am finding hard time caclulating the compression ratio of the decoded image.

I thought it was calculated as

```
CR = Size of decoded image/ size of original image
```

but am being told it is wrong.

Can someone please correct me on this.

And for the bit/pixel, is it also calculated as;

```
bpp= 8/CR ??
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I have seen the compression ration in other fields as: `Bytes used to store compressed file/bytes used to store original file`, optionally multiplied by 100%. Bit/ pixel would easily be calculated as `total number of bits/total number of pixels`.

Comment: yeah bytes is the size of the image so how would you calculate the compression ratio using the bit allocation?